# Symfony custom bundle - routing security / firewall error 500

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7, orocrm

My website is powered by Symfony 2.7 + OroCRM.
I made my own bundle with 2 new routes :

- /ipad/
- /ipad/admin

All is working well and i'm now trying to configure security / access control. For now, everybody can see the 2 pages with the URL. What I want is :

- /ipad/ visible for everybody
- /ipad/admin/ only visible for ROLE_ADMIN

In my security.yml, if I add :

```
security
    access_control
        [... existing rule]
        [... existing rule]
        [... existing rule]
        - { path: /ipad/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

... The 2 pages are unavailable (error 500) and the logs are :

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\InvalidDomainObjectException:
>   "$domainObject must either implement the DomainObjectInterface, or
>   have a method named "getId"." at
>   src/Oro/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Acl/Domain/ObjectIdAccessor.php line 27

I don't understand what's wrong, can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement DomanObjectEntity from DomainObjectInterface.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : I search in the database the "ROLE_ADMIN" doesn't exit, it's "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR".